# How to change CiviCRM Home to a different page (not Dashboard)?

Tags: menu, dashboard, civicrm-home

For some use-cases the CiviCRM Dashboard is not a helpful home base. Many users find it disorienting if the available dashlets are not useful to them.

So my question is simple: How can the mysite.org/civicrm be set to a different default page?

For example, I would like mysite.org/civicrm to default instead to the page shown at mysite.org/civicrm/contact/search?reset=1 so that all menu links that point to "CiviCRM Home" would end up at /civicrm/contact/search?reset=1

Comment: This really depends on the CMS.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since this path is hard-coded into CiviCRM, the best way to override it is probably a redirect. You could achieve this:

- Using the either the [redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) or [path redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_redirect) module for drupal.
- Using a plugin for Wordpress such as [redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).
- Using Apache's [mod-rewrite](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html).

Note that there are two paths you'd need to redirect from: `/civicrm` and `/civicrm/dashboard` as Civi treats the former as an alias of the latter and links do not consistently go to one or the other.

Comment: Thank you @Coleman for explaining that there is no CiviCRM-specific way to change it. I will use a redirect.

Comment: You're welcome. Also added a note about multiple paths pointing to the dashboard.

Comment: I ended up using drupal.org/project/redirect and I redirected both /civicrm and /civicrm/dashboard and it works perfectly. Thanks @Coleman